# RecordType field permissions in Metadata of Profile

Tags: custom-object, profile, metadata, record-type

I have one doubt --

Let say I have metadata of one profile =  "abc.profile"

Custom object = "Custom_object__c"

Fields in it = Field1__c
Standard Field = Record Type

Now If I see MetaData of my profile "abc.profile" , I can see that my Field1__c's field Permissions are listed there - Like

```
<fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>Custom_Object__c.Field1__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

Then Why I dont see any Standard Field / RecordType field in profile metadata ?

Answer could be : You can not make them Readable=False (You have to edit object permissions = False, don't access anything) but little more technical Explanation / solutions / work around will do better for me.

Thank you !

Comment: Did you assign your profile to the correct record type ? Usually it's under <layoutAssignments> section

Comment: Yes, I will look in there. But why so ? is the question I want to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally any ".profile" file will include recordtype data also. But this information will depend on how you choose to retrieve the profile. If you include, the field alone in your package xml then your profile file will contain metadata for field only. To get recordtype data you should include recordtype name in the package xml in unpackaged folder. see [Constructing salesforce project manifest.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_package.htm)
so in essence .profile files will show the metadata only for components explicitly specified in unpackaged/package.xml folder.

**Update:**
If you are using ANT, this is the structure of tags to be put in package xml:

```
<types>
<members>abc</members>
<name>Profile</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>sample</members>
<name>RecordType</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>CustomObject__c.CustomField__c</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Then your extract should have profile abc which contains recordtype info.

If you are using eclipse & extracting full repository, then the recordtype info should be there in abc.profile. If not, it is likely that the recordtype is not assigned to abc profile in salesforce.

Comment: I have extracted whole project repository, and searched for each profile - each object, found for no-one !

Comment: @NileshMendhe What tool are you using to extract? What does the package xml look like? Check if you have assigned recordtypes to abc.profile in salesforce?